# Place a text within a rectangle in specific position in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a rectangle and place a very long text inside of it. However, the code I am trying does not work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [gray!20] (-4, 0) -- (4, 0) --(4, -1) -- (-4, -1);
\draw (-4, -0.5) node[]{Εναλλακτική λύση των ερωτημάτων (γ') και (δ') από};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The MWE would be

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [gray!20] (-4, 0) -- (4, 0) --(4, -1) -- (-4, -1);
    \draw (-4, -0.5) node[]{Εναλλακτική λύση των ερωτημάτων (γ') και (δ') από};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The text floats outside of the rectangle. I want it to be placed at where the rectangle begins but to be inside. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an option specifying the text width. It's automatically left justified then:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}

\tikzstyle{drawrect}=[draw, rectangle,anchor=west, minimum height=2,
  minimum width=8,fill=gray!20,text width=7.9cm]


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [drawrect]  { The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.};
    %\fill [gray!20] (-4, 0) -- (4, 0) --(4, -1) -- (-4, -1);
   % \node at (-4, -0.5) {Εναλλακτική λύση των ερωτημάτων (γ') και (δ') από};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: Sorry, I couldn't run your code with Greek babel package.

Comment: Thank you.. no problem for the Greek package.