# How can I left-align the text in a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

How can I left align the text "Mi" inside the node? I assumed that align=left would work however the text is still centered.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=6pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=23mm,y=6mm,%
    mybox/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,minimum width=23mm, minimum height=6mm, align=left},%
    workday/.style={mybox,draw=black,align=left}]%

\node at (0,-1) [workday] {Mi};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `text width` instead of `minimum width`

Comment: Closely related: [Left alignment in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12973/134144)

Comment: `fontsize=6pt` isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an option specifying the text width. It's automatically left justified then:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=6pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=23mm,y=6mm,%
    mybox/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,minimum width=23mm, minimum height=6mm, align=left,text width=2cm},%
    workday/.style={mybox,draw=black,align=left}]%
\node at (0,-1) [workday] {Mi};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as cited--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12976/197451

--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347625/197451

Comment: When you answer using the suggestion indicated in a comment, it is fair to cite the comment. Please remember it for the future.

Comment: citing has been now done Sir

Comment: Thank you, but I am a lady

Comment: citing has been now done Ma'am